# Getting specific things from a site in android

Tags: java, android, http-get

So i'm working on a track and trace app.
And i need to pull information from this site:
http://www.postdanmark.dk/tracktrace/TrackTrace.do?i_stregkode=RA076673982CN

My problem is that i dont know how to pick this part:

1. september 2011  09:47   Ankommet til DANMARK
2. september 2011  07:17   Ankommet til omdeling 6710 Esbjerg V Posthus
3. september 2011  11:57   Udleveret til privat

and only that part.

Here's my code that downloads the whole html page:

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String getURL = "http://www.postdanmark.dk/tracktrace/TrackTrace.do?i_stregkode=RA076673982CN";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                    //do something with the response
                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

I have looked at several links and i cant seem to find anything that shows how to get a certain part of a html site like the:

```
<tbody>  

<tr> 
<td valign="top">19. september 2011</td>
<td valign="top">09:47</td>
<td valign="top">Ankommet til DANMARK</td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<td valign="top">20. september 2011</td>

<td valign="top">07:17</td>
<td valign="top">Ankommet til omdeling 6710 Esbjerg V Posthus</td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<td valign="top">20. september 2011</td>
<td valign="top">11:57</td>
<td valign="top">Udleveret til privat</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
```

I need my parser to get that part, but i haven't found or understood how :(

Can any of you show me an example on how to do it? :-/

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the HTML and pull out the data you want using something like TagSoup/etc. (not sure if that works on Android). You could *try* to pull it out using regex, but...

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Well android is java, so there must be some way in java, i don't know if the tagsoup method works in java, i have never do it before

Comment: and as i can see it in the source code of the site, i need to restrict the httpget to <tbody></tbody> and the content in between those 2 tags, and then get that parsed somehow to my layout.

Comment: The GET will get the page; you can't "restrict" the GET.

Comment: how do i "restrict" it to only get the <tbody> part of the site?

Comment: You don't; I thought I just said that. You get the entire page, then parse out the parts you want.

Comment: how do i parse the <tbody> part?

Comment: okay i have been looking at the code, trying to get it to read my track and trace site, but i cant get it to work, do you think you can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

try using the sax parser

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

you just give it an input stream to the site page and then you can select which tags to keep

here is an example:

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/sample-saxparser-in-android.html

Comment: i need to parse an html file, not an XML